# Javascript function for HTML that happens only once

Tags: javascript, java, html

So I have this function in Javascript that posts an alert message on the HTML Website each time a database entry is already in use.

Now the Problem is I want to print it only once for example with a "Overwrite all entries" button instead of the message coming each time.

Each time a database entry is already in use, the javascript has a case which cooperates with a java file (the java file sends the "databaseentryexists" for each entry) which is like this:

```
case 'databaseentryexists': AlertFunction("alert-warning"); break;
```

And Then the function itself works like this:

```
function AlertFunction(messagetype){

    var messagetype = "alert " + messagetype;   
    jQuery('<div/>', { class: messagetype
    }).html('Overwrite button').appendTo("#alertmessage1"); 

}
```

And in HTML it looks like this:

```
<div id="alertmessage1"></div>
```

How can I work it out that the "Overwrite" message only happens one time instead for every entry?

Comment: It depends on how the communication between client and server is done, because from my understanding, you make n requests to your server, and you got n responses, but you only want to notify the user once all responses are received. If it's basically XHR/Ajax http requests, you certainly got promises. You could wait for them to be all over with `Promise.all` and fire your alert from there, I think i'd do like that, but we cannot see enough to give accurate advice right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a variable flag that will check whether your overwrite message have already added or not like

```
var isOverwriteDone = false;

function AlertFunction(messagetype){
if(!isOverwriteDone ){
    isOverwriteDone = true;
    var messagetype = "alert " + messagetype;   
    jQuery('<div/>', { class: messagetype
    }).html('Overwrite button').appendTo("#alertmessage1"); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure:

```
const AlertFunction = (() => {
  let hasBeenCalled = false;

  return (messagetype) => {
    if (hasBeenCalled) return;

    var messagetype = "alert " + messagetype;

    hasBeenCalled = true;
    jQuery('<div/>', { class: messagetype }).html('Overwrite button').appendTo("#alertmessage1");
  }
})()
```

so that

```
AlertFunction("123"); // -> "alert 123"
AlertFunction("456"); // -> undefined
```

Please bear in mind that you cannot control how many times a function is called. What you can control is how many times the function body is executed. Be it a simple boolean flag or more complex underlying logic.